# Is PostgreSQL's Ltree module a good fit for threaded comments?

Tags: database, postgresql, tree, comments, hierarchy

I'm considering using PostgreSQL's [Ltree module](http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/postgres/gist/ltree/) in my application to help with threaded comments.  I've been eying it for a while to use for threaded comments.  I figure it would help with cases where you need to update a node and its children, like when you want to hide a comment and its replies.

I'm thinking ltree (or something like it) it would be useful if it was coupled with a traditional adjacency list ("comment_id"/"parent_comment_id").

Before taking the plunge into using ltree, I'm wondering a few things:

1. Are you, or have you, used ltree?  Is it what one might call "production ready"?
2. If so, what problems did you use it to solve?  Did it do a good job?
3. Do you think it is a good fit for a
   threaded comment system?

   4. If you used it, what did you use for the "text" part of the path?  Did you set up something like the DMOZ example they use "Top.Astronomy.Cosmology" or base it on something like the primary key "1.403.29.5"?
   5. Is there a better way to do this?  I'm a bit nervous using a nested list approach--everything I've read suggests that it isn't all to hot with UPDATES or INSERTS (don't you have to reorder the whole thing?).  I'm also not a CS major and that kind of data structure is something I might forget in the future.  Is anybody using nested lists for comments or something like it?

If it is of any help, here is the schema I'm considering:

```
CREATE TABLE comments (
    comment_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    parent_comment_id int REFERENCES comments(comment_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    thread_id int NOT NULL  REFERENCES threads(thread_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    path ltree NOT NULL,
    comment_body text NOT NULL,
    hide boolean not null default false
);
```

The "path" column, used by ltree, would look something like:

```
<thread_id>.<parent_comment_id_#1>.<parent_comment_id_#2>.<my_comment_id>
```

Is there anything wrong with using the primary keys in the path?  Should I be including the node's own primary key in the path?  If I did, would it make sense to put a unique index on it to serve as a constraint?

Comment: ltree is a 'materialized path' implementation. see http://www.dbazine.com/oracle/or-articles/tropashko4 for a comparison of possibile solutions, including more portable (but less efficient) methods such as nested sets.

Comment: feel free to add this as an answer.  i'm open to other ideas.  I've looked into nested sets, but they seem like a pain in the ass to implement and rather slow on updates/inserts (don't you have to shift everything down?).

Comment: oh, and I was thinking of using ltree in addition to the adjacency list.  hence "comment_id" and "parent_comment_id".  what I had in mind was to use ltree to speedup operations on a branch

Comment: Keep in mind that 8.4 will be bringing some of this functionality into the core (see http://developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs/postgres/queries-with.html ), so you might want to hold off until 8.4 is out if you're modifying existing code.

Comment: put this as an answer, it sounds like one to me.  I just might hold off... i love new postgresql releases--i always feel like a kid in a candy store :-)

Comment: On a cursory glance, I feel that ltree is not designed for deep hierarchies... I could be very wrong, of course...

Comment: i should reword this question a bit--everybody is answering it here :-)  your bit is kinda what I'm looking for, alex.  why is it not for deep hierarchies and what is "deep"?  20 nodes?  I couldn't see the thread getting that deeep (the code wouldn't let it)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Yes and yes;
2. Hierarchy of sections in a knowledge base (one of the implementations);
3. Yes;

The definition of one of the tables in question:

```
                                                   Table "knowledgebase.section"
           Column           |           Type           |                                  Modifiers
----------------------------+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 section_sid                | integer                  | not null default nextval('knowledgebase.section_section_sid_seq'::regclass)
 section                    | character varying        | not null
 description                | character varying        |
 path                       | ltree                    | not null
 is_active                  | boolean                  | not null default true
 role_sid                   | integer                  | not null
 last_modified_by           | integer                  | not null
 creation_datetime          | timestamp with time zone | not null default now()
 last_modification_datetime | timestamp with time zone | not null default now()
 is_expanded                | boolean                  | not null default false
 section_idx                | tsvector                 |
Indexes:
    "section_sid_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (section_sid)
    "section_section_key" UNIQUE, btree (section)
    "idxsection_idx" gist (section_idx)
    "path_gist_idx" gist (path)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "last_modified_by_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (last_modified_by) REFERENCES "user"."role"(role_sid) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
    "role_sid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (role_sid) REFERENCES "user"."role"(role_sid) ON  UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
Triggers:
    section_idx_update BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON knowledgebase.section FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE tsearch2('section_idx', 'section')
```

The "path" column uses the primary key as a label.

A sample of the current contents of that table (regarding the primary key and the "path" column):

```
  section_sid | path
 -------------+-------
           53 | 34.53
           56 | 56
           55 | 29.55
           35 | 35
           54 | 34.54
           37 | 30.37
          ... | ...
```

Comment: what is the path look like as a string?  are you using text, or numbers?

Comment: How do you make paths include their own id since it is calculated when it is inserted? Do you use a trigger, an `UPDATE`, or something else?

Answer (score 4):

I recommend anyone implementing hierarchical relationships in SQL read [Joe Celko's Trees and Hierarchies in SQL for Smarties](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558609202).

Traversing arbitrary depth parent child links can be very inefficient when using just a parent_id.  The book describes techniques that make this access fast.

One strategy (which I happen to use) can also be found for free in this series of articles:

- [Part 1](http://www.dbmsmag.com/9603d06.html)  (look for the section "Trees in SQL") ([Wayback link](https://web.archive.org/web/20081121131640/http://www.dbmsmag.com/9603d06.html))
- [Part 2](http://www.dbmsmag.com/9604d06.html) ([Wayback link](https://web.archive.org/web/20080517111145/http://www.dbmsmag.com/9604d06.html))
- [Part 3](http://www.dbmsmag.com/9605d06.html) ([Wayback link](https://web.archive.org/web/20080517111145/http://www.dbmsmag.com/9605d06.html))
- [Part 4](http://www.dbmsmag.com/9606d06.html) ([Wayback link](https://web.archive.org/web/20080517111145/http://www.dbmsmag.com/9606d06.html))

Answer (score 2):

Version 8.4 of PostgreSQL will be bringing Common Table Expressions functionality into the core with `WITH` and `WITH... RECURSIVE` expressions. If you're modifying old code, you may want to wait until 8.4 is released, as then you won't have to worry about any incompatibilities between Ltree and the new core syntax. If you're working with old code, or do not want to wait for 8.4, you will probably want to make sure you write code that is easily translatable to the new syntax, especially if you're changing an old schema or designing a new one.

See also:

- [The 8.4 manual entry on `WITH` queries and CTEs](http://developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs/postgres/queries-with.html)
- [A writeup with examples on the 8.4 implementation of CTEs](http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2008/10/07/waiting-for-84-common-table-expressions-with-queries/)

Comment: that is very, very cool.  That WITH stuff looks like it will be useful for more than just comments.  Finding tags and their related tags seems like another good candidate because it is doing some self-joins.