# Reference value of serial column in another column during same INSERT

Tags: sql, postgresql, auto-increment, sql-insert

I have a table with a SERIAL primary key, and also an ltree column, whose value I want to be the concatenation of those primary keys.  e.g.

```
id | path
----------
1    1
2    1.2
3    1.2.3
4    1.4
5    1.5
```

I'm curious if there's a way to do such an insert in one query, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO foo (id, ltree) VALUES (DEFAULT, THIS.id::text)
```

I'm probably overreaching here and trying to do in one query what I should be doing in two (grouped in a transaction).

Comment: That path doesn't look very queryable ..

Comment: My path values are based on this:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/607379/39529

Comment: PostgreSQL has recursion, common table expression, a lot easier and faster than your path solution/workaround.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use a CTE to retrieve the value from the sequence *once* and use it *repeatedly*:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT nextval('foo_id_seq') AS id
   )
INSERT INTO foo (id, ltree)
SELECT id, '1.' || id
FROM   cte;
```

The [CTE with a data-modifying command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) requires Postgres 9.1 or later.

If you are not sure about the name of the sequence, use 
[`pg_get_serial_sequence()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE) instead:

```
WITH i AS (
   SELECT nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('foo', 'id')) AS id
   )
INSERT INTO foo (id, ltree)
SELECT id, '1.' || id
FROM   i;
```

If the table name "foo" might not be unique across all schemas in the DB, schema-qualify it. And if the spelling of any name is non-standard, you have to double-quote:

```
pg_get_serial_sequence('"My_odd_Schema".foo', 'id')
```

---

Quick tests indicated [@Mark's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12433285/939860) with [`lastval()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html#FUNCTIONS-SEQUENCE-TABLE) *might* work too:

```
INSERT INTO foo (ltree) VALUES ('1.' || lastval());
```

- You can just leave `id` out of the query, the `serial` column will be assigned automatically. Makes no difference.
- There shouldn't be a race condition between rows. I [quote the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html):

> `currval`
>
> Return the value most recently obtained by `nextval` for this sequence in the current session. (An error is reported if `nextval` has
>   never been called for this sequence in this session.) **Because this is
>   returning a session-local value, it gives a predictable answer whether
>   or not other sessions have executed `nextval` since the current session
>   did.**
>
> This function requires `USAGE` or `SELECT` privilege on the sequence.
>
> `lastval`
>
> Return the value most recently returned by `nextval` in the current session. This function is **identical to `currval`, except** that instead of
>   taking the sequence name as an argument it refers to whichever
>   sequence `nextval` was most recently applied to in the current session.
>   It is an error to call `lastval` if `nextval` has not yet been called in
>   the current session.
>
> This function requires `USAGE` or `SELECT` privilege on the last used sequence.

Bold emphasis mine.

**But**, as [@Bernard commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433075/reference-value-of-serial-column-in-another-column-during-same-insert/12433285#comment76902318_12433446), it can fail after all: there is no guarantee that the default value is filled (and `nextval()` called in the process) *before* `lastval()` is called to fill the 2nd column `ltree`. So stick with the first solution and `nextval()` to be sure.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that `nextval()` will be called first to find the next primary key, so that `lastval()` won't throw an error?

Comment: Your second suggestion throws a `55000 ERROR: lastval is not yet defined in this session` on PostgreSQL 9.5.

Comment: @Bernard: Thanks for the corrective, I updated accordingly. Added a way to without knowing the sequence name while being at it.

Answer (score 4):

This worked in my test:

```
INSERT INTO foo (id, ltree) VALUES (DEFAULT, (SELECT last_value from foo_id_seq));
```

I think there's a race condition there if two INSERTs are happening at the same time, since this references the last sequence value, instead of the current row.  I would personally be more inclined to do this (pseudo-code):

```
my $id = SELECT nextval('foo_id_seq');
INSERT INTO foo (id, ltree) VALUES ($id, '$id');
```