# How to get last inserted Uuid?

Tags: postgresql

When creating Uuid columns on psql, I cannot get LAST_VAL to work:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
    id UUID DEFAULT gen_random_uuid() PRIMARY KEY,
    title text NOT NULL
);

# insert into t (title) values ('hello'), ('world');
INSERT 0 2
# select LASTVAL();
ERROR:  lastval is not yet defined in this session
```

Comment: On the insert append `returning id`.

Comment: @AllanWind thanks. That is the work around. But I wanted to understand why this is breaks the usual LASTVAL() functionality, as I am documenting an interface from another language into postgresql.

Comment: Lastval() works for a sequence , not for any other function or data type. Returning is by far the best solution anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To clear up the confusion, `nextval()` and `lastval()` are [sequence manipulation functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html), and [`gen_random_uuid()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-uuid.html) has nothing to do with sequences. You are barking up the wrong tree.

For the record, `currval()` and `lastval()` are perfectly safe to use in combination with `nextval()`. Both return a session-local value, concurrent sessions (= concurrent transactions, since there can only be a single transaction per session at any point in time) do not interfere with it. See:

- [Reference value of serial column in another column during same INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433075/reference-value-of-serial-column-in-another-column-during-same-insert/12433446#12433446)

Use the `RETURNING` clause as has already been suggested. Works in any case.