# Create a new row for every missing reference in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

In short, I am trying to do this:

Setup:

```sql
create table info(
  info_id serial primary key, 
  info_text text
);
create table product(
  prod_id serial primary key, 
  info_id int /*unique*/, 
  description text unique, 
  price int);

insert into product (description, price) values ('pen', 1), ('notebook', 2), ('ruller', 3);
```

Now I am trying to update all `product` rows where the `info_id` reference is `null`, by way of creating a new row in the `info` table and then assign the reference to it to the product:

```sql
with new_info as (insert into info default values returning info_id)
update product
set info_id = (select info_id from new_info)
where product.info_id is null;
```

**The problem is that it only creates one info and then assigns all products to it. I expect it to create one companion info row for each product.**

```sql
select * from product, info where product.info_id = info.info_id;
```

```
 prod_id | info_id | description | price | info_id | info_text 
---------+---------+-------------+-------+---------+-----------
       1 |       1 | pen         |     1 |       1 | [null]
       2 |       1 | notebook    |     2 |       1 | [null]
       3 |       1 | ruller      |     3 |       1 | [null]
```

Comment: why have three different products the same info text?  if they have thr same info it would be correct to have the same id when it is normalized) so oyu need to come uo with a why to determine whitch row will get  the newly created info first before trying to imlplement something

Comment: You were hoping that EACH update would create a new entry in `info` with a new `info_id`?  SQL can't do that.  However, that's easy enough to do with two separate queries: one to populate `info` from `product`, one to update `product`.

Comment: @nbk sorry about confusion, I have changed the question to clarify a little bit. Important end result is that every product ends up having a separate info row associated with it. The database schema is given to me unfortunately - I can't change it.

Comment: @TimRoberts, thank you for your suggestion. I see what you are saying, but if I create info rows upfront, I should store their info_id somewhere to then use for product updates... 

Comment: i would write a function where xou give a text and return the new id, a mass update with different text would need a table where info text and product id where link with the above mentioned function, you would get new (or existing ids depending if the text is already there, but as is said earlier think in normalized terms, that helps, the database can not invent associations that are not here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This creates a separate new row in table `info` and backfills a reference to it for every null in `product.info_id`:

```sql
WITH upd AS (
   UPDATE product
   SET    info_id = nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('info', 'info_id'))
   WHERE  info_id IS NULL
   RETURNING info_id
   )
INSERT INTO info (info_id)
SELECT info_id
FROM   upd;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pJ0Umdv4)

Even works with a FK constraint in place.

Related:

- [Reference value of serial column in another column during same INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433075/reference-value-of-serial-column-in-another-column-during-same-insert/12433446#12433446)
- [How to deal with mutually dependent inserts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24813000/how-to-deal-with-mutually-dependent-inserts/24816197#24816197)